# Maxima: symbolic matrix simplifications

Tags: maxima

I am trying to use Maxima to simplify a symbolic matrix expression. I've learned that there are the non-commutative multiplication `.` and the non-commutative power `^^` operators.
So I can write something like the following:

```
e1: X^^(-1) . (X^^(-1) + Y^^(-1))^^(-1) . Y^^(-1);
```

How could I force Maxima to apply the rule of the inverse matrix product here?

`A^^(-1) . B^^(-1). C^^(-1)` is `(C.B.A)^^(-1)`, and then the initial expression is simplified to `(X+Y)^^(-1)`.